# search and replace in the output resulte of a php code

Tags: php

I have made the following code in a PHP file to list the content of a directory
and it works just fine

```
<?php

  $dir = opendir(getcwd());
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    echo "filename : ". $file ."<br />";
  }
  closedir($dir);

?>
```

I want to make some changes in the output (string) result. I have tried a search and replace PHP code `str_replace()` but I have been unable to get it to work.

Comment: What kind of changes do you want to make with str_reaplace ??? or what output are you expecting

Comment: What 3 and 5 lines ...  give example like this .. i want `aaaaaa.html` to be `aaaabbbb.html` ...  its not very clear

Comment: Oh .. i get you now ... you want to output only `files.php` and also remove all the dot ??

Comment: You just want to display `filename : files.php , filename : index.html  and filename : FTP-ORDI-AHST (10-07-2012 22_29_25).mht ) ??? right

Comment: Do you want to `rename` it in the folder or .. just the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
$dir = opendir(getcwd());
$max = 3 ;
$current = 0 ;
print('<table id="hor-minimalist-a" summary="Employee Pay Sheet"><tbody>');
while ( ($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ) {
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..") {
        continue;
    }
    $current++;
    if($current > $max)
        print("<tr>");
    printf("<td>%s</td>",$file);
    if($current >= $max)
    {
        print("</tr>");
        $current = 0;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
print('</tbody></table>');
```

Comment: this will remove the 2 results that contain dots
i will need this code too
thank you for your answer

Comment: there's only one more thing please
the output data are shown in a table
[link for the page](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/test.php)
the table contains one <tr> tag
and the php code generates a <td> tag for each result
 `echo "<td>". $file ."</td>";`
i want the table to be dynamic so after each 3 <td> tags it creats a <tr> tag
and the table will be in the end composed of 3 colons and a lot of lines (depending on how many result the php code come up with)

Comment: @Tbaik Amine am not sure i get want you want ....  you also did not accept my answer ... Use expected output so that i can understand what you want

Comment: i did accept your answer and i thank you for it ..
both answers were useful for me .. and i can only accept one in this website
[the result that i expect](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/the%20wanted%20result.html)
and not like this [link](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/test.php)
i can't vote for your answer either because i need 15 point of privilege in this website so i can vote in this website .. i don't have reputation to do this

Comment: @Tbaik Amine you an only accpet one question .... Have seen your test link .. how do you want it arranged ???

Comment: i want it to be like this [the result that i expect](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/the%20wanted%20result.html)
but dynamically

Comment: Ok >> make it a new question ... add your code and the output you want ... i would update it with the solution

Comment: Don't worry i would just update the answer

Comment: @Tbaik Amine see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

You can use `if(!is_dir($file))` condition in your code

```
  $dir = opendir(getcwd());
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

    if(!is_dir($file))
      {
            echo "filename : ". $file ."<br />";
    }       
  }
  closedir($dir);

?>
```

Comment: thank you .. i needed also to specify if the output result is a directory or not !
your answer was useful